# Banach subspace of Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces

How to prove that subspace of Banach space is also Banach space?

I believe that's only true if subspace is closed. However, I don't understand why we can't take non-closed subspace. Is there any counterexample of non-closed subspaces that will not be Banach although space was Banach?

Comment: Hint: A supset of a complete metric space is complete if and only if it's closed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that if $X$ is a Banach space and $F\subseteq X$ is a subspace. Then $F$ is a Banach space with the restricted norm of $X$ into $F$ if and only if $F$ is closed in $X$.

A counterexample is the following.

Consider $X=\ell_{\infty}$ with the supremum norm given by
$$||x||_{\infty}=\sup\bigl\{|x(n)|:\,n\in \mathbb{N}\bigr\},$$
for every $x=(x(n))_{n}$ in $\ell_{\infty}$. Now, consider as $F$ the space $c_{00}$ of eventually zero sequences, i.e.
$$c_{00}=\bigl\{x\in \ell_{\infty}:\, \exists\, m \in \mathbb{N}\, \text{such that}\, x(n)=0\, \text{for every}\, n\geq m\bigr\}.$$
Then, $c_{00}$ is not a Banach space, for the sequence $(x_k)_k$ given by
$$x_k=\biggl(1,\, \frac{1}{2},\,...,\,\frac{1}{k},\,0,\,0,\,...\biggr)$$
is a Cauchy sequence since $||x_k-x_m||_{\infty}=1/k$, for every $k>m$ but not convergent in $c_{00}$. Indeed, for the last claim observe that $(x_k)_k$ converges to the element
$$x=\biggl(1,\,\frac{1}{2},\,...,\,\frac{1}{k},\,\frac{1}{k+1},\,...\biggr)$$
in $\ell_{\infty}$ which is not in $c_{00}$.

**Edit: Why $(x_k)_k$ is not convergent on $c_{00}$?**

Let $x$ be the point in $\ell_{00}$ with $x=(1,1/2,...,1/n,...)$. Then, observe that for every $k$,
$$||x-x_k||_{\infty}=||(0,0,...,\frac{1}{k+1},\frac{1}{k+2},...)||_{\infty}=\frac{1}{k+1}.$$
Hence, $||x-x_k||_{\infty}\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$. If ($x_k)_k$ where convergent on $c_{00}$ to some point $y$ we would have
$$||x-y||_{\infty}\leq ||x-x_k||_{\infty}+||x_k-y||_{\infty}\to 0,$$
as $k\to \infty$. In other words, $x=y$. But $x$ **does not** belong to $c_{00}$.

Comment: But why (x_k)_k is not convergent in c00?

Comment: @NixoN I edited my previous answer, you can check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the subset of differentiable functions of the set of continuous functions defined on a compact interval.